# How to change 'no results found' in Select2 wordpress plugin to a different language

Tags: wordpress, jquery-select2

How do I change the select2 'results not found' language depending on what language the user chose in wordpress?

```js
 noResults: function () {
      return 'No results found';
    },
```

Comment: How are you integration select2 into wordpress? are you using a form plugin or something? If so, maybe the plugin "Loco Translate" may find this string so you can translate it.

Comment: I have the 'Loco Translate' plugin but it doesn't have the string. I was able to find the string inside the select2 JS file however changing it in there doesn't reflect...

Answer (score 0):

You can try overwritting the value when initiating select2. In my example, your select field has the class ".select2". Please remember to check in the source code of your page, if your select field has a class already. There should be one, I guess. If there is no class or id, try accessing it via a parent element. This way you do not have to change any code, just add a script.

To overwrite the value with js, put this code at the end of your wordpress page template, or inside the footer.php of your theme file. The ".select2" after "$" is the class of your field.

```
<script>
    $('.select2').select2({
        language: {
            noResults: function () {
              return "This is your <strong>no results</strong> message.";
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

If the console says "$ is not a function", you can try replacing the "$" with "jQuery".

So you do not change the value in select2 itself, but overwrite it when initiating. Since you want to change the output, I think is solution suits your problem.